# --user curl equivalent in httr

Tags: r, curl, httr

This is, I presume, some really simple curl code that I am trying to translate into a httr format.

```
curl -X POST \
  --user '<email>:<password>' \
  --header 'user-key: <user_key>' \
  --url https://api.m.com/v1/clients
```

So far I have tried

```
library(httr)    
POST(url = "https://api.m.com/v1/clients",
                 add_headers('user-key' = "userkey",
                             user = 'email:password'))
```

But without success. Any hints on what is wrong here? Is there an httr equivalent to `--user` in the curl code?

Comment: [`curlconverter`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) can be used to translate cURL command-lines into `httr` calls but you should be using the `authenticate()` option in `POST` or `GET` calls when passing in credentials from `--user`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(httr)  

username <- 'my_user_name'
password <- 'my_password'

POST(url = "https://api.m.com/v1/clients", 
                 config = authenticate(username, password), add_headers("Content-Type: application/json"),
                 body = upload_file('./my_file.json'),
                 encode = 'json')
```